PublishOffer moves item to a different category, but category was the one suggested
I'm trying to list some shoes on EBay UK, via the rest APIs, but when I try an create a offer in the suggested category, it returns an error saying it's moved to a different category.
"warnings": 
[
 {
   "errorId": 25401,
   "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
   "subdomain": "Selling",
   "category": "REQUEST",
   "message": "Invalid listing option(s) removed. This product belongs to a different category, so the category has been changed."
 }
]

My methods are:
To get the correct category, I call this:
https://api.ebay.com/commerce/taxonomy/v1/category_tree/3/get_category_suggestions?q=\"New Balance Sneakers Unisex Trainers\"
3 = EBAY_GB tree
and it suggests
"categoryId": "95672", "categoryName": "Trainers"
So I create a listing, and then an offer:
POST: https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/offer/5..6/publish
{
 "availableQuantity":1,
 "categoryId":"95672", <-- suggested category id
 "format":"FIXED_PRICE",
 "listingDuration":"GTC",
 "listingPolicies": {"fulfillmentPolicyId":"2..6","paymentPolicyId":"2..6","returnPolicyId":"2..6"},
  "marketplaceId":"EBAY_GB",
  "merchantLocationKey":"default",
  "pricingSummary":
   { 
    "price": {"currency":"GBP","value":"8000.00"}},
   "sku":"..."
 }

But the response here is the error at the top.
What am I doing wrong?
